# I am not able access methods of any existing class in eclipse. Auto suggest functionality to select methods is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I created one java-maven project in Eclipse IDE.
added three dependencies in POM.xml file( selenium, WebDriverManager and testNG)
I created instance of WebDriver but when trying to access webdriver methods using that instance variable, webdriver method list is not coming.

```java
package SeleniumTutorial.JavaProject005;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class LoginTest {
    
    public static WebDriver driver;
    
    @Test
    public void launchBrowser() {
        WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
        
        driver.
        //here on giving dot, I am not getting web driver methods like get(), getTitle etc()
        
    }
}
```

My Pom.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SeleniumTutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaProject005</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>JavaProject005</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse => Right Click On Project => Maven => Click "Update Project"